# How to highlight the first row of this python code (to_excel)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

Is it possible to highlight the first row of these dataframes so when they are stacked vertically into excel they highlight in yellow.

import pandas as pd

```
data1 = """
class    precision   recall 
<18      0.0125         12           
18-24    0.0250         16 
25-34    0.00350         4
"""
data2 = """
class    precision   recall 
<18      0               0           
18-24    0.25            6 
25-34    0.35            5
"""

#create 2 df for sample
df1 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data1), sep='\s+')
df1.name = "Dataframe1"
df2 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data2), sep='\s+')
df2.name = "Dataframe2"
print(df1);print(df2)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('e:\\test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook=writer.book
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('Result')
writer.sheets['Result'] = worksheet
worksheet.write_string(0, 0, df1.name)

df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Result',startrow=1 , startcol=0)
worksheet.write_string(df1.shape[0] + 4, 0, df2.name)
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Result',startrow=df1.shape[0] + 5, startcol=0)
```

Was thinking maybe along the lines of these (or better):

```
import xlwings as xw
df.to_excel(finalname,index=False,header=False)
wb = xw.Book(finalname)
```

and

```
wb.sheets['yoursheet'].range('A').color = (169,169,169)
```

and

```
wb.sheets['sheet1'].range('A').api.Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Not sure how to mold these to fit the excel code.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have full control over the formatting.  Pandas uses a package called XlsxWriter for that.  https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: Was using Xlsxwriter, but I've found it has limitations here. Cannot stack dataframes and maintain their formatting/style. Is there another way to do this aside from Xlsxwriter?